# I need to write a VBA to convert formula to value but leave as formula if the first column is empty

Tags: excel, vba

i am a complete noob to vba's but is this possible?#
I need to write a VBA to convert formula to value but leave as formula if the first column is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it what you need:

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    'change Sheet1 to suit
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'range with formulas
        Set rng = .Range("B1:B100")

        For Each cell In rng
            If Trim(.Range("A" & cell.Row)) <> "" Then cell.Value = cell.Value
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Simco, is it possible to put a before save in and it do it for more than one range with formulas?

Comment: sorry, don't understand what you need, can you rephrase please and maybe add some example:)

Comment: each row has 6 formula in and i need these all saving as values when we save the spreadsheet at the end of the day, but as it is updated daily i dont want it to do this on the rows that we are yet to use but already have formulas in.

Comment: if I undestood you correctly, you should change `Set rng = .Range("B1:B100")` to, say, `Set rng = .Range("B1:G100")`

Comment: it is telling me my subscript is out of range?

Comment: it seems to be the first

Comment: @user3351591, first line is `Dim rng As Range` - it can't trigger any error. Please, show exactly in what line of code you got an error.

Comment: it highlights Sub test()? sorry if im annoying you

Comment: 1) have you changed sheet name in line `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` to correct one for you? 2) what range address are you using in this line: `Set rng = .Range("B1:B100")`?

Comment: i hvae amended it to sheet6 and range to ("C1:K300"). still the same error?

Comment: First of all check whether your workbook contains `sheet6` (maybe there is some typo). Next, when you got an error message `subscript is out of range` there are also four buttons: "Continue", "End", "Debug", "Help". Press, please, "Debug" button and say what line of code would be yellow.

Comment: it doesnt give me the debug option but i now have a run-time error '9'?

Comment: Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    'change Sheet1 to suit
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet6")
        'range with formulas
        Set rng = .Range("C1:K300")

        For Each cell In rng
            If Trim(.Range("A" & cell.Row)) <> "" Then cell.Value = cell.Value
        Next
    End With
End Sub 

what i have entered and i ge tthe run-time error 9 subscript out of range?

Comment: @user3351591, do you have this pop-up message-box? https://www.dropbox.com/s/a6abubd3m2562l1/1.png If yes, please, press `Debug` button, otherwise I can't help you. Also check whether your workbook really contains `sheet6` (maybe there is some typo - additional spaces and so on)

Comment: ok i'll have a look, thank you very much for helping me i know i have been a pain.

Comment: @user3351591, try to evaluate this test sub: `Sub test2(): ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet6").Activate: End Sub` If you still have subscript out of range -  your sheet name is uncorrect